# How do I create a simple hypertext link in my app?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I am just trying to make a simple TextView open a link in a browser when clicked.

**XML:**

```
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/account_sign_up_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_link"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:onClick="signUpLink"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

**Java:**

```
    public class signUpLink extends Activity {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out why Eclipse keeps throwing this error.

**Error:**

```
Illegal modifier for the local class signUpLink; only abstract or final is permitted
```

**Update:**

My first problem was that it was in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` so I took it out of there.

Ultimately I came up with this:

```
public void signUpLink(View v){
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://mysite.com/signup"); 
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void is an invalid type for the variable signUpLink

Method declarations need to be made in the class definition. When trying to declare a method inside another method, errors similar to this are reported.

```
public class SignUpLink extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
           ...

    }
    public void signUpLink(View v) {
        //....Code here
    }
}
```

and Follow the naming convention of class.

Comment: Now I get `Illegal modifier for the local class SignUpLink; only abstract or final is permitted`

Comment: @TGMCians a named inner class **can** be public.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public class signUpLink extends Activity {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    }
}
```

to:

```
public void signUpLink(View v) {
    //Code from onClick(View v) goes here
}
```

This method must go into the Activity class where you're using the XML layout. When you specify `onClick` as an XML attribute, Android looks for a method with that name that takes a `View` as an argument in the Activity the layout has been inflated into.

Earlier, you were creating a new class, not a new method.

Comment: Now I get: `void is an invalid type for the variable signUpLink`

Comment: Uh, post your complete Activity into your question as an edit. That shouldn't be happening. You're probably declaring it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use Html.fromHtml

```
   Text1.setText(
        Html.fromHtml(
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a> "));
    Text1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet

```
    TextView url = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myWebSite));
    Linkify.addLinks(url, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

this worked for me.Dont forget to define the internet permisson in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your xml layout specifies the `TextView`'s `onClick` action as "`signUpLink`," the same `Activity` whose content view is that xml file needs to implement that method like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
    }

    public void signUpLink(final View view) {
        // Do signup action
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you want to use this layout in a `Fragment` and keep the logic encapsulated to the `Fragment` itself, you'd need to do something more like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup parent, final Bundle icicle) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, parent, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_link).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            void onClick(View v) {
                /*MyFragment.this.*/signUpLink(v);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void signUpLink(final View view) {
        // Do signup action
    }
}
```